# <video> image feed is in mirror image, how to transform image to non-mirror image

Tags: html, css, image, html5-video, ip-camera

***functionality:***

User to stand in front of camera and take a picture.

***What has been done:***

Made use of of a `<video>` to capture motion image and have created a "Take Picture" button to capture the image to impose a still image. Have also incorporated a Zoom feature as well.

***Issue:***

The image is mirrored. Therefore, when user moves left, the image in the video feed will move right and when user moves left, the image in the video feed will move right.

I have changed the following `transform:rotateY()`, however, it is still giving me the same functionality whereby when user moves left, the image in the camera feed moves right and vice versa. Hence, what have I done wrong and how do I rectify the following issue.

```css
.camera_feed_flip {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  /* Firefox */
  transform: scale(1.0);
}
```

```html
<div id="CameraFeed" align="center" style="position:absolute; widths:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=7; top:600px; left:0px; ">

  <video id="video" width="1300px" height="1350" class="camera_feed_flip" style="position:absolute; z-index:16; top: 600px; left:-110px" autoplay></video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the transform css at all, but it strikes me that you are rotating the image by 0 degrees (and therefore not changing it at all) . Shouldn't  it be by 180 degrees?

```
.camera_feed_flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  /* Firefox */
  transform: scale(1.0);
}
```

but then I have never used this css. I may not be accurate and therefore gvinig you an incorrect solution - sorry if that's the case :)

Comment: Thanks!!it is supposed to be `180 deg`, but strangely nothing has changed.

Comment: anyway, Thanks!!for some reason, it is not reading the `class`. got it